# Apache and vsftp file permission

Tags: php, apache2

I have setup apache according to this article 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP
and I have created a new site config in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite`
and changed the document root and directory to :

```
DocumentRoot /home/gapton/public_html
<Dictory />
..
..
</Directory>
<Directory /home/gapton/public_html/>
...
...
...
...
</Directory>
```

and I `sudo a2dissite default && sudo a2ensite mysite` to disable and enable them, restarted apache2 and things are working.

I then setup vsftpd and config the `vsftpd.conf` file to :

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
```

connect via Notepad++ with the user 'gapton' and I created a file called `test.php` under `home/gapton/public_html`. It would not be readable by Apache it seems. I did `sudo chmod -R 755 ~/public_html` and it would load alright.

However any subsequent files created via vsftpd will not be readable.

Since I have logged in to the only account `gapton` when connecting via FTP, then any newly created file should be owned by `gapton` right? What happens when apache tries to access a file/folder location, what credentials does it access it by?

How do I config it so that all files created by `gapton` can be read by apache? (Also, is it at all advisable?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

In **older** version of vsftpd, the umask they apply when writing file was by default 022.

In the current version, such default value has been changed to 077. This mask read `4` write `2` and execute `1` for everyone except the owner.

Changing the umask value in the `vsftpd.conf` file back to 022 has solved my problem. Hope this help future users of vsftpd facing the same issue.